# How to init with a generic NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: swift, core-data

Wondering how to init a class that contains a fetched results controller?
The compiler says that T is an undeclared type. I have a couple of dynamic tables that draw their data from a fetchedResultsController. If i could make the inject frc generic that would eliminate a bunch of duplicate code and make things more maintainable.

```
class DynamicTableData: NSObject {

    let frc: NSFetchedResultsController<T>

    init(frc: NSFetchedResultsController<T>) {
        self.frc = frc
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your your generic type should conform to **NSFetchRequestResult**

```
class DynamicTableData<T:NSFetchRequestResult>: NSObject {
    let frc: NSFetchedResultsController<T>
    init(frc: NSFetchedResultsController<T>) {
    self.frc = frc
    super.init()
   }
}
```